# CANNOT get FFserver stream going

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming, http-live-streaming, ffserver

I want to preface this question with the fact that I am very very new to ffmpeg and even newer to ffserver.

I cannot, for the life of me, get this thing going.
I get:

`"Too large number of skipped frames 882933314374 > 60000"`

Also, ffplay gives me `first frame is no keyframe`

Here is my ffserver.conf file

```
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 1000
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 2000000
NoDefaults

###############################################################################################

<Feed test.ffm>
    File /tmp/test.ffm
    FileMaxSize 10000M
    ACL ALLOW localhost
</Feed>

<Stream status.html>
Format status

# Only allow local people to get the status
    ACL allow localhost
</Stream>

<Stream test.avi>
    Feed test.ffm
    Format avi
    ACL ALLOW localhost
    ACL ALLOW 192.168.1.0
    NoAudio
    VideoSize 3840x2160
    VideoFrameRate 30
    Preroll 10
</Stream>

###############################################################################################
```

And here is my ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -i smaller.avi http://localhost:8090/test.ffm
```

I've been fighting with this thing all day, googling like a madman the entire time. What am I doing wrong? Any help will be welcomed enthusiastically.

Answer (score 1):

These are my notes as I'm currently working through a similar process:

**Video Streaming from ffserver for Raspberry PI - Unoptimized**

Follow this tutorial: (I know people don't like links but this tut worked)
https://oscarliang.com/webcam-streaming-video-raspberry-pi-via-browser/

Download ffmpeg for windows (or linux)

`git clone https://git.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg`

// Keep your ffserver.conf simple at first

```html
HTTPPort 8090
HTTPBindAddress 0.0.0.0
MaxHTTPConnections 1000
MaxClients 10
MaxBandwidth 2000000
NoDefaults

###############################################################################################

<Feed test.ffm>
    File /tmp/test.ffm
    FileMaxSize 10M
</Feed>

<Stream test.avi>
    Feed test.avi
    Format mjpeg
    VideoSize 640x480
    VideoFrameRate 20
    VideoBitRate 2000
    VideoQMin 2
    VideoQMax 10
</Stream>
```

Put endpoint at `http://<localhost>/webcam.mjpeg`

Makesure webcam.sh contains:

`ffserver -f /etc/ffserver.conf \
 & ffmpeg -v verbose \
          -r 30 \
          -s 640x480 \
          -f video4linux2 \
          -i /dev/video0 http://localhost/webcam.ffm`

Run the following:

// Use the following instead of vlc as this has faster streaming

Win:
ffplay.exe http://localhost/webcam.mjpeg

Linux:
ffplay http://localhost/webcam.mjpeg